# How to pass output of ps x | grep rclone to kill command?

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs, ps

This is the output:

```
$ ps x | grep rclone
   7111 ?        Sl     0:00 rclone mount xxx
   7112 ?        Sl     0:00 rclone mount xxx
   7113 ?        Sl    10:16 rclone mount xxx
   9843 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto rclone
```

I am thinking of somehow passing (pipe maybe) the second column of info, i.e. 7111, 7112, 7113 to be killed like so:

```
kill 7111
kill 7112
kill 7113
```

Xargs is all I have in mind, but not sure if that is correct nor the way to use it.

Thank you!

Fedora 35 KDE if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what `killall` and `pkill` are for: `killall rclone` or `pkill rclone`.

Comment: `pkill -v` is **not** verbose!!! It inherits from `grep` _inversion_.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on Fedora your `ps` should support `--no-headers` and `-C` options; so you can skip `grep`:

```
ps --no-headers -C rclone -opid | xargs -r kill
```

The standard way to skip headers, it to specify an empty header:

```
ps -C rclone -o pid= | xargs -r kill
```

(`-C` is not standard though, it comes from HP/UX. The `-r` option of `xargs` is not standard either, a GNU extension).